# Order queryset filter in django using orderby and supplying a function

Tags: python, sql, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to return some locations from my sql db, ordered by distance from my current long lat.  I have built an external function that takes my long/lat and somewhere else's long/lat and returns a float.  However, struggling with getting this to run in my query.  My query currently looks like this:

```
class GallaryView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Place.objects.filter(business="Gallary").
        order_by(
            long_lat_distance(51.501521, -0.141944,Place.lattitude,Place.longitude))
    serializer_class = PlaceSerializer
```

With this, I get DifferedAttribute errors.

I'm pretty lost on this.  If anyone's got any pointers I'd be very grateful

Cheers!

Comment: May I add, each Place object has a latitude and longitude field.

I have tried setting long_lat_distance as a method in the class which inherits self, and 2 external arguments.  But when trying to use that method as a way of ordering, it expects 3 arguments